# Got "java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long" error

Tags: mysql, eclipse, jdbc

I have installed MySQL Server, MySQL Workbench and Connector/J through mysql-installer-community-8.0.20.0(means software are of same version) and also download and installed Eclipse IDE 2020-06(4.16.0) in Windows 7(64 bit).

MySQL Server Credentials are:
database(schema): mayank
username: mayank
password: Hello@1234

My issue is I am able to connect to mayank database through Workbench with above mentioned credentials but while I am trying to create a new database connection(By right clicking on Database Connection folder-->New-->Entered above credentials) in Eclipse(Database Perspective) it shows the following error:-
**Note**:I clicked on "Test Connection"when I got following Error:
**Ping failed!.**
with the following details...

```
java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:988)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:974)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.buildCollationMapping(ConnectionImpl.java:1062)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImpl.java:3556)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2513)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2283)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:822)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:404)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:317)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.createConnection(JDBCConnection.java:328)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.internalCreateConnection(DriverConnectionBase.java:105)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.open(DriverConnectionBase.java:54)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.open(JDBCConnection.java:96)
at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.internal.mysql.connection.JDBCMySQLConnectionFactory.createConnection(JDBCMySQLConnectionFactory.java:28)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionFactoryProvider.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryProvider.java:83)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionProfile.createConnection(ConnectionProfile.java:359)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.createTestConnection(PingJob.java:76)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.run(PingJob.java:59)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
```

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.buildCollationMapping(ConnectionImpl.java:1007)
... 22 more

But before Testing connection, I have defined MYSQL Driver Definition by clicking on Windows>Preferences>Data Management>Connectivity>DriverDefinitions>Add> than I have select MySQL JDBC Driver (system version 5.1) and adding Jar from location="C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\Connector J 8.0\mysql-connector-java-8.0.20".

That is all, kindly help.

Comment: Can you paste the query?

Comment: The error means you are using an older version of MySQL Connector/J 5.1.x to connect. Make sure your classpath does not contain more than one MySQL Connector/J.